# When i give a long value in a column, the design breaks down

Tags: css, jsp, jsf

[Design Breaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21Rid.png)

As you can see, my scroll bar does not work because of the design break down.
This is a rich table in div class. Is it possible to make max length value for this column in jsp file? How can i prevent it.

Comment: Need full code (HTML with CSS). Screenshot is not enough

Comment: I think you forgot to add your code after "Here is my code of this part in jsp"

Comment: All plain html/css related. Nothing jsp or jsf. Jsf is in this regard just an html generator. look at the client-sode html and css and start from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decide the maximum width you wish your column to be and set `overflow` to `hidden`. Additionally you can use CSS to automatically insert an ellipsis to indicate that there is truncated text. Here is a sample selector.

```
.overflow-ellipsis {
  max-width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

and a snippet:

```css
.overflow-ellipsis {
  max-width: 250px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="overflow-ellipsis">
  0123456789012345678901234567890123456789
</div>
```